# Responsive div doesn't return to position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When the page initially loads the links div is fine, when it moves down to it's responsive position, it's fine, when I resize the webpage back up, it doesn't go quite back to the original position.

To see this error, go to the pen, reduce the width of the page to quite small (the link will move the center bottom), then increase the width again.

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/joeljfischer/pen/zsFLj) and [Full Page Link](http://cdpn.io/zsFLj)

```
<nav class="bond-header">
  <h1>
    <a href="/home/">Home Link</a>
  </h1>

  <div class="bond-header-links">
    <h6>
      <a href="/about/">About</a>
    </h6>
  </div>
</nav>

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 131.25%;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
  html {
    font-size: 112.5%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 530px) {
  html {
    font-size: 87.5%;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #272725;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
hr {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-style: solid;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.bond-header {
  max-width: 38rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin: 2rem auto 4rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
.bond-header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media (max-width: 860px) {
  .bond-header {
    max-width: 93%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 530px) {
  .bond-header {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.bond-header .bond-header-links {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 530px) {
  .bond-header .bond-header-links {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
  }
}
.bond-header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Exo 2", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.62rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 530px) {
  .bond-header h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
.bond-header h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.bond-header h6 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.bond-header h6 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.bond-header h6 a .bond-current-location-link {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.bond-header h6 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Try adding relevant code to the question itself and not just links.

Comment: I can, and i will at your suggestion. It just didnt seem to be very useful since it seems meaningless if you cant see what it does in the context of the page. And actually useful code that runs would be a click away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a weird one.  If you use Chrome Inspector to toggle off and back on the `float:right` that is set on `.bond-header .bond-header-links` you get the same issue (it's not just when you resize).  I think the layout is getting confused with the inline-block on your `h1` but not sure.

Anyway, it's fixed if you change your `bond-header h1` to `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` then remove the float for smaller screens.

```
.bond-header h1 {
  /*display: inline-block; REMOVE */
  float: left; /* ADD */
  font-family: "Exo 2", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.62rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 530px) {
  .bond-header h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxFGD)**

Comment: Took me a moment to figure out why mine still wasn't working. You also added the `float: none` to the media query. Finding that fixed it. Odd bug, thanks for the help tracking it down. I'm guessing it's a rendering engine bug of some sort? I can't imagine that would be expected behavior.

Comment: Yeah see bottom part of the code in my answer.  I moved your media queries so I could see them better.  I've seen something similar on Stack Overflow before but can't remember when it was which is annoying